# If $x\le y$, prove $\lfloor{x}\rfloor \le \lfloor{y}\rfloor$

Tags: calculus, inequality, real-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I've just started my infinitesimal course, and I would like to see if I got the essence of floor right.

> Let $x, y \in \mathbb R$ and $x\le y$ , prove that $\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor\le \left\lfloor y \right\rfloor$.

So, we know from the definition of floor that:

A. $\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor\le x < \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor +1$

B. $\left\lfloor y \right\rfloor \le y < \left\lfloor y \right\rfloor +1$

Now, since $x\le y$:

$\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor \le x \le y \rightarrow \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor \le y$

Also from the definition, we understand:

A. $\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor = max\{n\in \mathbb Z | n\le x\} $

B. $\left\lfloor y \right\rfloor = max\{n\in \mathbb Z | n \le y\}$

Is it okay to derive from here since $x\le y$ and $\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor \le y$

That also $\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor \le \left\lfloor y \right\rfloor$?

Thanks!

Comment: Use \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor to write $\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor$.

Comment: Ah, I see. On writing the question it was fine until I uploaded it. Will fix.

Comment: `$\lfloor x\rfloor$` gives $\lfloor x\rfloor$

Comment: @Gary Or just `\lfloor x \rfloor` if what you're flooring doesn't have tall things in it. The `\left` and `\right` are for automatic bracket size adjustment, and unnecessary in this case as the standard size works just fine.

Comment: It follows from $\{n\in \mathbb Z | n\le x\} \subset \{n\in \mathbb Z | n\le y\}$

Comment: @MartinR I was just about to type the very same thing, except I think it should be $\subseteq$ rather than $\subset$.

Comment: @saulspatz Most people wo write "$\subset$" use it to denote a not necessarily proper subset. I try to avoid it completely …

Comment: @saulspatz: There are different conventions. As I learned it, $A \subset B$ does not exclude that $A=B$.

Comment: @MartinR Which is a shame, because it would be nice if $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ universally mirrored $<$ and $\leq$. But as it stands, we have to resort to $\subsetneq$ and $\subseteq$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go

$$\lfloor x\rfloor\le x\le y\lt\lfloor y\rfloor+1\implies-1\lt\lfloor y\rfloor-\lfloor x\rfloor\implies0\le\lfloor y\rfloor-\lfloor x\rfloor$$

where the final implication uses the fact that $\lfloor y\rfloor-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is an *integer* greater than $-1$.

Comment: Very elegant solution, I like that one a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since floor is defined as a maximum of a bounded above set of numbers, you want to use the following property of maxima of bounded above subsets of $\mathbb R$:

> When $A\subseteq B$ then $\max A \le \max B$.

Now note that when $x\le y$ you have
$$
\{\,n\in\mathbb Z\mid n\le x\,\} \subseteq \{\,n\in\mathbb Z\mid n\le y\,\}
$$
by transitivity of $\le$ and thus the above identity yields $\lfloor x\rfloor \le \lfloor y\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

Another (perhaps more direct) way too see this is to split the problem into two cases:
if $y \ge \lfloor x \rfloor + 1$ then $\lfloor y \rfloor \ge \lfloor x \rfloor + 1$ since this quantity is in $\mathbb{Z}$, hence $\lfloor y \rfloor \ge \lfloor x \rfloor $.

Otherwise, $x \le y < \lfloor x \rfloor + 1$ in which case $\lfloor y \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor$ since this is the biggest integer smaller than $y$.

In both case we conclude that $\lfloor x \rfloor \le \lfloor y \rfloor$.

Comment: You probably want $x \le y < \lfloor x \rfloor + 1$ in the second case.

Comment: Edited. Thanks !